# Every time a Java program runs, is it compiled automatically?

Tags: java

Every time a Java program runs, is it compiled automatically?
I'm leaning towards No because lets say if I'm not using eclipse but am using command line, I have to compile (javac) before running the program. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: no unless you order IDE (eclipse, intellij, netbeans, etc) to do it

Comment: You are correct. Eclipse is compiling the Java files every time you run. Like you said, you can manually compile with javac

Comment: I encourage the close voter to explain where they got the idea that "is it compiled automatically?" is caused by a problem that can't be reproduced.

Comment: @tier1. Yes on IDE. No in default

Comment: This would be pretty easy to test. Write a program that prints `Hello, world`. Then edit it to print `Hello, Dolly` and run it again.

Answer (score 8):

No, java programs are not automatically compiled every time they run.

Java programs must be explicitly compiled before they can be executed. Your IDE may perform that function for you each time you ask it to run the app - but that's the IDE, not Java, triggering the compilation.